# Angular Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to update a value `system`  into an object `telecom`, but in this stage it displays this error

> Cannot assign to read only property 'system' of object '[object
>   Object]'

```
this.organization.telecoms.forEach((telecom: Telecom) => 
   telecom.system = 'test'
);
console.log(this.organization);

export class Organization {
    public effectiveDate?: EffectiveDate;
    public identifiers?: IdentifierOrg[];
    public kilometerZones?: KilometerZone[];
    public telecoms?: Telecom[];
}

export class Telecom {
    public system?: string;
    public value?: string;
}
```

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(telecom, 'system', { value: 'test' });`

Comment: (Or you remove the `readonly` property)

Comment: @trichetriche who can i remove the readonly property ?

Comment: try removing `: Telecom` from `foreach`

Comment: Can also try with `forEach((telecom: any)`

Comment: By any means if you are using ngrx and ngrx store freeze then you will not able to update system property. You may need to write separate action and its reducer.

Comment: try `telecom['system'] = 'test'`

Answer (score -1):

Try initalize classes.

Checkout this app from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rghoep)

```
export class AppComponent  {
  organization: Organization;

  constructor() {
    this.organization = new Organization();
    this.organization.telecoms = [
      {
        system: 'foo',
        value: 'val'
      },
      {
        system: 'foo2',
        value: 'val2'
      },
      {
        system: 'foo3',
        value: 'val3'
      }
    ]
    this.organization.telecoms.forEach((telecom: Telecom) => 
      telecom.system = 'test'
    );
    console.log(this.organization);
  }
}

export class Organization {
    public telecoms?: Telecom[];
}

export class Telecom {
    public system?: string;
    public value?: string;
}
```